Network Home Setup with Raspberry Pi as a router

I'm looking for a way to setup my home network, with a Raspberry Pi 3 as the router. My ISP is using ``PPPOE`` to deliver service. 
The ideal would be to have both a wired network and a wifi network on the other that share the same sub-net. 
I'm thinking about using one of those USB Ethernet dongles to have two Ethernet output on the pi and the onboard WiFi for the AP.
Here is a very basic diagram:


How should I go about setting up something like this? 
Network is not my training field so it might look very simple to some, apologies for that.
Thank you for idea help or hint you can provide! 

If it were me, I would still put a commercial router/firewall device between my network and the internet. To skip this means it is now totally up to you to keep the firewall up to date and hardened against attacks.

See Tour to see how this site works
and How do I ask a good question?

Don't expect much speed with this setup. The onboard NIC is slow, and a USB2 NIC isn't much faster. As for onboard wifi, don't expect to be able to connect more than about 3 devices sitting in the same room as the pi
